# Usage of shebang in file header: is there any option to pass multiple arguments in shebang

Tags: bash, namespaces, hashbang

I am using a different namespace for my python file execution. using a shebang/hashbang, to execute this script (/bin/bash -c ).

problem faced is shebang only accepts a single argument. even if i pass multiple args its treating it as a single string.

shebang used:
`#!/sbin/ip netns exec tmp <executable>`

Experiment:

1. single executable using : `#!/sbin/ip`

   ```
   Object " tmp" is unknown, try "ip help".
   ```
2. one arg shebang in tmp : `#!/sbin/ip netns`

   ```
   $/bin/bash -c  tmp
   Command "tmp" is unknown, try "ip netns help".
   ```
3. with two arg shebang used in tmp: `#!/sbin/ip netns exec`

   ```
   $/bin/bash -c  tmp
   Object "netns exec" is unknown, try "ip help".
   ```

   - its picking "netns exec" as a single argument
4. full cmd used

   shebang used in tmp : `#!/sbin/ip netns exec global python`

   ```
   $/bin/bash -c  tmp
   Object "netns exec global python" is unknown, try "ip help".
   ```

Is there any way to pass multiple argumenets to shebang executable other than chaining files.

Comment: Interpretation of the shebang depends on the OS (I think generally the kernel controls it). What OS are you using? BTW, I tried to clean up the formatting & spelling of your question, please make sure I didn't make any errors (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for info about code/literal section formatting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux (and other OSs I believe) only split the shebang string once, at the first whitespace. So you can only ever pass one argument.

When you do `#!/sbin/ip netns exec tmp <executable>`, `ip` sees one argument string: `netns exec tmp <executable>` (including spaces).

But GNU `env` added the `-S` option for splitting shebang arguments. It's also available on FreeBSD `env`. But not busybox `env`.

So if you launch your interpreter using `env -S`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S command -a -b -c
```

`env` will split the three arguments on white space, and pass them to `command`. `env` of course is seeing the single argument `-S command -a -b -c`, but it can parse this.

I don't know enough about namespaces to know if this is a good idea, but it seemed to work for me:

```
$ sudo ip netns add test
$ sudo ip netns identify
# (empty)

$ cat /tmp/netns-shebang-test
#!/usr/bin/env -S ip netns exec test bash

echo "$BASH_VERSION"
echo "$0"
ip netns identify

$ sudo /tmp/netns-shebang-test
5.1.16(1)-release
/tmp/netns-shebang-test-script
test
```

I'm showing bash, but it also worked with a similar python script. I will repeat that I don't know enough about namespaces to know if this is a good approach or not.